# Win firewall doesn't block a particular application

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-connection, windows-firewall

I need to block internet access for a particular application (the SlimBrowser), but haven't succeeded yet. I added several rules to the Windows Firewall to completely block this app, but it still accesses internet without any restriction. Other apps (like Firefox) can be blocked by the firewall rules without any problem.

**Q:** How can I block this app?

**Details:** SlimBrowser is a wrapper around Internet Explorer. It uses two processes: `sbframe.exe` and `sbrender.exe`. I created the Win firewall blocking rules for both processes, both outbound and inbound (though the latter shouldn't be necessary). In Process Explorer I see that SBRender.exe still communicates with internet (https) directly, even though the blocking rules should prohibit it.

In the Windows Firewall, I have set block all protocols, ports and IPs in all profiles.

The Windows Firewall is turned on and works fine. When I create the same blocking rules for Firefox, it is really blocked, it is not able to communicate with internet. My antivirus doesn't have its own firewall.

I use Windows 7 Pro x64. Internet Explorer is uninstalled, though its core is still there (otherwise SlimBrowser wouldn't work).

Comment: @Biswapriyo I added the rules using the wizard: `Outbound rules > New rule: Program = <path to exe>, Action=Block the connection, Profile=check all, Name=... > Finish`. The same way I added the rule for Firefox, but that worked.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I already block both executables, and moreover not only outbound but also inbound. See the "Details" section of my question.